# Android AES decryption returning rare characters

Tags: java, android, aes

I'm trying to decrypt a String text with the AES algorithm and I found many tutorials but still getting the same error when I try to decrypt the String.

Here is my class:

```
   EditText inputText, inputPass;
TextView out;
Button btnEnc, btnDec;
String outputString;
private static final String AES_MODE = "AES";

View.OnClickListener encryption= new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            outputString= encrypt(inputText.getText().toString(),inputPass.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.setText(outputString);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener decryption= new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            outputString= decrypt(outputString,inputPass.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.setText(outputString);
    }
};

private String encrypt(String data, String pass)throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec key= generateKey(pass);
    Cipher c= Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] encVal= c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue= Base64.encodeToString(encVal,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return  encryptedValue;
}
private String decrypt(String cadena, String password)throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec keySpec= generateKey(password);
    Cipher c= Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
    byte[] decValue= Base64.decode(cadena, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String decryptedValue= new String((decValue));
    return decryptedValue;
}
private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest digest= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes= password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    byte[] key= digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec= new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

The problem is when I try to retrieve the Decrypted string because it returns this:

[image]

As you can see, the output text contains Unicode characters and not the text that I've encrypted. What would be the problem?

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: it was this line that i forgot to add:  byte[] decValue= c.doFinal(Base64.decode(cadena, Base64.DEFAULT));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually call your cipher in the decrypt method.

```
private String decrypt(String cadena, String password)throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec keySpec= generateKey(password);
    Cipher c= Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
    byte[] decValue= c.doFinal(Base64.decode(cadena, Base64.DEFAULT));
    //               ^^^^^^^^^  add this
    String decryptedValue= new String((decValue));
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

Furthermore, you should always explicitly specify an encoding when converting from a `byte[]` to a `String` or vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean? in wich part?

Comment: here `data.getBytes()` and here `new String((decValue))`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice.. this works fine, but when i read an encrypted AES String the characters still showing, This String its created with UTF8 Encoding and i tried to specify the encoding on the decrypt method but still getting the same result...